# Save button in soft keyboard instead of enter in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to implement save button instead of enter in soft keyboard, and listener on this button, how can i do it?

```
input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

how to handle this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create `DoneOnEditorActionListener` and set to your `EditText` like

```
 class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and set to your `EditText` like

```
edit_Notes.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
```

Comment: onEditorAction not getting the call back in BootomSheetfragment